# How to generate random unique 16 digit number in asp.net without collision

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, random, guid

how can i generate 16 digit unique random numbers without any repetition in c# asp.net, as i have read the concept of GUID which generate characters along with numbers but i don't want characters

kindly suggest is there any way to acheive it

Comment: If you create a series of numbers without repetition, then they cannot be random.

Comment: Start with 1 and increment *(seriously)*

Comment: I dont want series,i want completely random numbers of 16 digit

Comment: Use a table to hold the numbers you've already distribued and use some simple scheme to get a next number. It could go like this: `get a random number, while not available: increment. write as used.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a random number using the Random class:

```
private static Random RNG = new Random();

public string Create16DigitString()
{
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  while (builder.Length < 16) 
  {
    builder.Append(RNG.Next(10).ToString());
  }
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

Ensuring that there are no collisions requires you to track all results that you have previously returned, which is in effect a memory leak (NB I do not recommend that you use this - keeping track of all previous results is a bad idea, rely on the entropy of a random string of up to 16 characters, if you want more uniqueness, increase the entropy, but I shall include it to show how it *could* be done):

```
private static HashSet<string> Results = new HashSet<string>();

public string CreateUnique16DigitString()
{
  var result = Create16DigitString();
  while (!Results.Add(result))
  {
    result = Create16DigitString();
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: it worked but i want to ask weather this method is feasible for generating large amount of numbers(like in millions) will it get reapeated

Comment: @VivekSingh All I can offer is a probability. There are 10^16 combinations of a 16 digit number, let us call this `N`, creating `k` numbers gives a probability that they are all unique of e^{\frac{-k(k-1)}{2N}}. Using 10 million as k, this gives a probability of 99.004983473%

Comment: Rather than a hash set, could you write the previously returned numbers into a database? You would still have an ever increasing table full of numbers to search through, but that shouldn't be such a burden on memory as storing all previous numbers in the hash.

Comment: @nedlud Yes, you *could*, however IMO this is still a bad idea - it does not scale well.

Comment: Thanks @rich.okelly I can see where it doesn't scale, but what *would* be a scalable solution if db and hash both don't scale? (I have a similar issue to the OP and wonder how best to solve it)

Comment: @nedlud Increase the entropy. A GUID is Globally Unique by name, it achieves this via a massive amount of entropy (2^128 bits). In your case the situation may be different to GUIDs in that you are in control of them and may likely have some shared knowledge that can be further used to decrease the likelihood of a collision (eg if times are coordinated, encoding the current time in a part of the value) If you *absolutely* must guarantee uniqueness (a statistical guarantee is not sufficient) then a centralised source is the only option left available to you.