# How to generate 16 digit card number and 4 digit pin number using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am working on a project .
My requirement is that i need to generate 16 digit card number and 4 digit pin number .As soon as the person registers he should get a unique 16 digit number and pin number through mail and store the details in the database with the corresponding id.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: how can i generate 16 digit unique number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate random unique 16 digit number in asp.net without collision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891942/how-to-generate-random-unique-16-digit-number-in-asp-net-without-collision)

Comment: Generate one random number between 0 and 9, and do this 16 times in a loop, and concatenate the results.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go

```
    DECLARE @CardNr VARCHAR(20), @looper INT, @rand INT, @pin INT;
    SET @pin = LEFT(rand()*10000,4);
    SET @CardNr = ''
     SET @looper = 1
            WHILE @looper <= 16
            BEGIN 
                SET @rand = rand()*10
                SET @CardNr = @CardNr +'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1),@rand)
                IF (@looper % 4)=0 AND @looper < 16
                    SET @CardNr = @CardNr + '-'
                SET @looper = @looper + 1
            END
    SELECT @CardNr CardNr,@pin Pin
```

You might also want to do a duplicate check before using the number.