# Generating a 12 digit unique number for dynamodb?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

When a user submits a form, I need to generate a 12-digit unique Id for them. I have thought of a few options, but not sure which is the best one or if there might be another way:

1. Pre-generate and store unique ids.  When the user submits a form, grab an id and delete it so it can't be used again.
2. Make a random 12-digit unique id, check if it has been used, if not, use it.  If it has been used, recreate another unique id. Keep doing this until I found a non-used unique id.

I can't use GUIDS or else I would use that, so if anyone has any suggestions, it would be great.

I am using the .NET AWS SDK

I thought about storing the numbers 2 million to 50 million as a hash key in a table.  Then on the client side, doing something like:

`new Random().Next(2000000,50000000)`

Then I would query the dynamotable for the random number returned, if I find it, I would delete it so it can't be used again, but I feel as if more users get unique ids, the random numbers would miss more frequently

Comment: Are you storing these IDs in a database? If so can't you use the ID that's being (hopefully) generated incrementally? And then do uniqueId.ToString("D12");

Comment: Yes I am storing the IDs in a dynamodb table.  They are unique per user.  But it was my understanding the dynamodb does not support auto increment keys

Comment: Consider using a timestamp as a basis for the ID.

Comment: @Amy - Can you elaborate as to what you mean by 'timestamp as a basis'.  Is it possible to generate a GUID and perform some hash on it that would return a 12-digit key?

Comment: Sure, it's simple enough.  Take the current time, get the ticks since some recent epoch (maybe today?).  Now append a random number to bring it up to 12 digits.  If you, say, reserve 9 digits for the timestamp and 3 digits for random, you are unlikely to get any collisions.  It would take multiple IDs generated *at the exact same time* to collide on the random number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random unique 16 digit number in asp.net without collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891942/how-to-generate-random-unique-16-digit-number-in-asp-net-without-collision)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
string uniqueId="";
Random randomizer = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
uniqueId+= randomizer.Next(0, 10);
}
```

That way you're randomizing the integers and you're sure it has the 12 unique numbers, then you'll have to query the DB, if it exists, run the function again and check until it returns nothing.

Comment: If the service/process writing this ID allows for concurrent calls (which is most likely) generating a random and making sure it doesn't exist before writing it doesn't guarantee uniqueness since other concurrent call might be doing the same.